# Bash_alias, run a script with a parameter and close console

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I just created a script that runs a command using a parameter like so:

```
(firefox "localhost/?id=""$1" &)
```

I created the alias like so:

```
alias gotoid='/myscript.sh
```

As you can see, my script requires the parameter $1 to run. What I want is to be able to run my script using `gotoid 3` for example and have the console automatically close without closing the Firefox window. When I change the alias to `alias gotoid='/myscript.sh && exit"`, it starts firefox at the URL but doesn't take my parameter anymore, replacing the number going into `id` by `(saw)`.

How can I make an alias for my script that allows the insertion of a parameter and close the console right after?

Thanks in advance.